# Single trace width calculator for impedance matching

Tags: antenna, impedance, impedance-matching, pcb-antenna

I would like to calculate the trace width of a dipole PCB antenna in order to match a 50ohm impedance.

[image: dipole]

Obviously, there is no ground on the bottom side.

All the impedance matching trace width calculator seem to consider that there is a ground plane on bottom. Here is a couple of calculator links:

https://www.pcbway.com/pcb_prototype/impedance_calculator.html

https://www.eeweb.com/tools/microstrip/

How can I calculate the optimized trace width for 50ohm impedance? Can I discard the impact of the ground plane in my particular case?

Comment: The antenna doesn't carry a guided wave. If it did, it wouldn't radiate. Therefore the impedance seen looking into the antenna can't depend only on the transverses geometry (trace width, dielctric thickness) of the trace. It must also depend on the length of the trace, the feed-point, any nearby loading elements, etc.

Comment: @thePhoton So how to calculate an approximation of the impedance based on width, FR4 and thickness?

Comment: You can't. The impedance of the antenna **can't** depend on only those things.